# Proof that there are No Modulo Invertible Polynomials with f(1) = 0

Tags: polynomials

I was reading an article from the NTRU Cryptosystem (probably the first one): [NTRU: A Ring-Based Public Key Cryptosystem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.8422&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

And I don't know how to prove the assertion he makes in parenthesis in paragraph 2.2: that a polynomial satisfying f(1) = 0 can never be invertible.

Does anyone have a proof or a link to one?

Thanks.

Comment: That should be wrong, consider $f(x)=1-x$.

Comment: What does invertible mean in this context? Of course, there is no $g(x)$ for which $f(x)g(x)=1$.

Comment: Well, in the context of the article... It's modular invertibility basically.

Comment: The operation here is the product $(\sum F_i X^i)\circledast (\sum G_i X^i) = \sum H_i X^i$ with $H_k = \sum_{i + j\equiv k\pmod{N}} F_i G_j$.